# Android : Changing camera Permission externally from settings causes apps shared preferences clears

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

1. open the app ask for camera permissions supply permission (saved data in shared preferences)
2. minimize app, app goes to background
3. go to settings page revoke camera permissions
4. again came back to app causes shared preference data null

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: irrespective of shared preferences, that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: may be it's not related to revoke permission, may be what make this happens is simply closing and reopen the app, try this, do steps 1 & 2, then force close app (from settings) then do step 4 and check preferences data

Answer (score 1):

For activity you should check shared preference on onCreate state or in SplashActivity and for fragments you should pass the sharedPreference state to mainactivity class.

Firstly check the sharedPreference state and make a boolean variable which will check permission from the manifest like below :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ShortCutPrefs", 0);
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("isPermitted", false)) {

            if (per == false) {
                if ((getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);

return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (per == false) {
                    if ((getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
return;
                }
            }
```

and the permission checking part :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ShortCutPrefs", 0);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isPermitted", true);
                editor.commit();
                per = true;
                setData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied to check you device details, grant this app permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

This way you can check if someone has removed permission from settings and ask them at the start of your app.

Good Luck!